Optimizing complex select Oracle Query
I've a below select Query which is taking lot of time when data is huge.
It is a join from 4 diffrent tables and I want to create a view for it.
I'm not able to find any optimizing techniques to make it return faster results
Table defination
CREATE TABLE TABLE_DEALS
   ("ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL, 
    "DEAL_NUM" VARCHAR2(50),
    "EXTERNAL_ID" NUMBER(20,0),
    "ECM_TXN_ID" NUMBER(20,0),
    "DEAL_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "OVERALLOTMENT_EXERCISED" NUMBER(20,5),
    "APP_VERSION" NUMBER(3,0),
    "OPUS_VERSION" NUMBER(3,0),
    "CREATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "UPDATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
   PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
   );
   
CREATE TABLE TABLE_SYNDICATES
   ("SYNDICATE_ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL, 
    "REVENUE_ID" NUMBER(20,0),
    "SYNDICATE_CODE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "SYNDICATE_NAME" VARCHAR2(350),
    "IDENTIFIER" VARCHAR2(50),
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "CREATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "UPDATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
   PRIMARY KEY ("SYNDICATE_ID"),
   FOREIGN KEY ("REVENUE_ID")  REFERENCES "TABLE_DEALS" ("ID") 
   );
   
      
   CREATE TABLE TABLE_FEES
   ("FEE_ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL , 
    "REVENUE_ID" NUMBER(20,0), 
    "IDENTIFIER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CREATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "UPDATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("FEE_ID"),
     FOREIGN KEY ("REVENUE_ID")  REFERENCES "TABLE_DEALS" ("ID")  
   );
   
   CREATE TABLE TABLE_DEAL_ATTRIBUTES
   ("DEAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL, 
    "DEAL_NUM" VARCHAR2(50),
    "EXTERNAL_ID" NUMBER(20,0),
    "SYNDICATE_CODE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "IDENTIFIER" VARCHAR2(50),
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "USER_EDITED" NUMBER(1),
    "CREATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "UPDATE_TS" TIMESTAMP (6),
   PRIMARY KEY ("DEAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
   );

Select statement :
select deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.APP_VERSION, syn.syndicate_code,
    MAX(syn.syndicate_name) as syndicate_NAME,
    MAX(deal.DEAL_TYPE) as DEAL_TYPE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='COMMITMENT' AND syn.TYPE='UNDERWRITING_COMMITMENT' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS UNDERWRITING_COMMITMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='COMMITMENT' AND syn.TYPE='COMM_SHARES' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS COMM_SHARES,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='RETAIL_RETENTION' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS RETAIL_RETENTION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='DIRECTED_SHARES' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS DIRECTED_SHARES,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='TOTAL_RETAIL' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS TOTAL_RETAIL,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='GROSS_SPREAD' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS GROSS_SPREAD,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='UW_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='UW_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)) AS UW_FEE,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)) AS MANAGEMENT_FEE,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN syn.VALUE END)) AS SELLING_CONCESSION,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='RETAIL_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='RETAIL_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)) AS RETAIL_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS MANAGEMENT_FEE_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='UW_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS UW_FEE_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS SELLING_CONCESSION_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='INCENTIVE_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS INCENTIVE_FEE_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='GROSS_SPREAD_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS GROSS_SPREAD_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='YIELD' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS YIELD,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='GLOBAL_COORDINATOR' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='GLOBAL_COORDINATOR' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS GLOBAL_COORDINATOR,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='GLOBAL_COORDINATOR_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS GLOBAL_COORDINATOR_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='UNDERWRITING' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS UNDERWRITING,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='UNDERWRITING_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS UNDERWRITING_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='MANAGEMENT' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS MANAGEMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS MANAGEMENT_PER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS SELL_CONCESSION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS SELL_CONCESSION_PER,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='DESIGNATION' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='DESIGNATION' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS DESIGNATION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='ADJUSTED_DESIGNATION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS ADJUSTED_DESIGNATION,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='INCENTIVE_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='INCENTIVE' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS INCENTIVE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='INCENTIVE_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS INCENTIVE_PER,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='SPONSOR_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='SPONSOR' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS SPONSOR,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='PRAEPICIUM' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='PRAEPICIUM' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS PRAEPICIUM, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='RETAIL_UNDERWRITING' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS RETAIL_UNDERWRITING,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='DIRECTED_SHARE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS DIRECTED_SHARE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='TOTAL' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS TOTAL,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='USE_INCENTIVE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS USE_INCENTIVE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END) AS POT_SPLIT_PER,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='RE_ALLOWANCE' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='RE_ALLOWANCE' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS RE_ALLOWANCE,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN attr.VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN fee.VALUE END)) AS INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES' AND fee.TYPE='EXPENSE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS EXPENSE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='REIMBURSEMENT_AMOUNT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS REIMBURSEMENT_AMOUNT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='IS_CITI_ENTITY' THEN attr.VALUE END) as IS_CITI_ENTITY,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='IS_BND' THEN attr.VALUE END) as IS_BND,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='syndicate_ROLE' THEN attr.VALUE END) as syndicate_ROLE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='CARVEOUT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS CARVEOUT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='CARVEOUT_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS CARVEOUT_ADJUSTMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='RETAIL_SELL_CONCESSION' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS RETAIL_SELL_CONCESSION,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='ADJUSTED_UW_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS ADJUSTED_UW_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='ADJUSTED_MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS ADJUSTED_MANAGEMENT_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='TOTAL_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS TOTAL_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='GROSS_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS GROSS_FEE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='DESIGNATION_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS DESIGNATION_ADJUSTMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='OUT_OF_POCKET_EXPENSE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS OUT_OF_POCKET_EXPENSE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='STABILIZATION_EXPENSE' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS STABILIZATION_EXPENSE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='STABILIZATION_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS STABILIZATION_ADJUSTMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='INITIAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS INITIAL_SETTLEMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='FINAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS FINAL_SETTLEMENT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES' AND attr.TYPE='TOTAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END) AS TOTAL_SETTLEMENT
    from TABLE_DEALS deal
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_SYNDICATES syn ON deal.ID = syn.revenue_id
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_FEES fee ON deal.ID = fee.revenue_id
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_ATTRIBUTES attr ON deal.DEAL_NUM = attr.DEAL_NUM AND deal.EXTERNAL_ID = attr.EXTERNAL_ID AND syn.syndicate_code = attr.syndicate_CODE
where (deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.APP_version, deal.create_ts) in (select d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID, MAX(d.APP_version), MAX(create_ts) from TABLEDEALS d group by d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID)
group by deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.app_version, syn.syndicate_code;

I created some indexes but still no major difference in the performance.
Index
CREATE INDEX idx_table_deals ON TABLE_DEALS (deal_num, EXTERNAL_ID, app_version, create_ts); 

CREATE INDEX idx_table_syndicates ON TABLE_SYNDICATES (revenue_id, SYNDICATE_code); 

CREATE INDEX idx_table_fees ON TABLE_FEES (revenue_id); 

CREATE INDEX idx_table_attributes ON TABLE_ATTRIBUTES (deal_num, EXTERNAL_ID, SYNDICATE_CODE);

Below is the query plan
Plan hash value: 1513026688
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                                     |   367 | 93952 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                          |                                                     |   367 | 93952 |   114   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                                                     |   367 | 93952 |   113   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                                                     |    23 |  5244 |    67   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                                                     |    23 |  4002 |    21   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI               |                                                     |     1 |    97 |    19   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       VIEW                              | VW_NSO_1                                            |  4105 |   160K|    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        HASH GROUP BY                    |                                                     |  4105 |   112K|    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TABLE_DEALS                                         |  4105 |   112K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE_DEALS                                         |  4105 |   228K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE_SYNDICATES                                    |    23 |  1771 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | idx_table_syndicates                                |    23 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | TABLE_DEAL_ATTRIBUTES                               |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | idx_table_attributes                                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | TABLE_FEES                                          |    16 |   448 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | idx_table_fees                                      |    16 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("DEAL"."deal_num"="deal_num" AND "DEAL"."EXTERNAL_ID"="EXTERNAL_ID" AND "DEAL"."APP_VERSION"="MAX(D.APP_VERSION)" AND 
              "DEAL"."CREATE_TS"="MAX(CREATE_TS)")
  11 - access("DEAL"."ID"="SYN"."REVENUE_ID"(+))
  13 - access("DEAL"."deal_num"="ATTR"."deal_num"(+) AND "DEAL"."EXTERNAL_ID"="ATTR"."EXTERNAL_ID"(+) AND 
              "SYN"."BROKER_CODE"="ATTR"."BROKER_CODE"(+))
  15 - access("DEAL"."ID"="FEE"."REVENUE_ID"(+))
 
Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan

Can someone help me

Please update your question with a detailed EXPLAIN PLAN for the query

As mentioned in the tag wiki for the query-optimization tag you used. please  include query plans and table and index definitions in your question. Also see this DBA FAQ.

@AlexPoole Sorry didnt read the tag. Thanks for letting me know

I think it's important to note the statement "I want to create a view for it." A view isn't a query anybody executes, so you can't tune a view, nor does an execution plan generated by the vie code by itself mean anything. You can only tune a query that uses the view, as the real executing SQL is a combination of both. You'd need to show us how that view is going to be used and what execution plan you get then. For example, if you intend to do select * from myview where customer_id =1234 that is entirely different than select * from myview.

@PaulW View is just a thought. At the end i want the above select query to return data at the quickest

That above query by itself has no filters. If by "quickest" you mean complete its work (return all data) as fast as possible, then you don't want to use indexes. Throw some parallelism at it and ensure your execution plan shows all hash joins and full table scans. If on the other hand you are timing until you get your first row in a database client to show up, that's a meaningless measure. The reason it delays to give you the first row is that hash join deep in the plan. You only get immediate rows back if it's nested loops the whole way. But that is not necessarily what's best.

In case the data doesn't change very often, consider having a look at the concept of Materialized Views: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view

Without any filters you're best off with hash joins and some parallelism. Try this hint out:
select /*+ USE_HASH(deal syn fee attr) PARALLEL(16) */ 
    deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.APP_VERSION, syn.syndicate_code,
    MAX(syn.syndicate_name) as syndicate_NAME,
    . . . [clip] . . .
 from TABLE_DEALS deal
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_SYNDICATES syn ON deal.ID = syn.revenue_id
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_FEES fee ON deal.ID = fee.revenue_id
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_ATTRIBUTES attr ON deal.DEAL_NUM = attr.DEAL_NUM AND deal.EXTERNAL_ID = attr.EXTERNAL_ID AND syn.syndicate_code = attr.syndicate_CODE
where (deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.APP_version, deal.create_ts) in (select d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID, MAX(d.APP_version), MAX(create_ts) from TABLEDEALS d group by d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID)
group by deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.app_version, syn.syndicate_code;

Just ensure you are measuring throughput (time to the last row), not response time (time to the first row). If you want the fastest response then that'd be an entirely different (opposite, in fact) approach that would ensure nested loops and index access at every step. In the vast majority of cases in the database world we want to optimize for throughput.

You can try pivoting before JOINing:
WITH syn AS (
  SELECT syn.revenue_id,
         syn.syndicate_code,
         MAX(syn.syndicate_name) as syndicate_NAME,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='COMMITMENT' AND syn.TYPE='UNDERWRITING_COMMITMENT' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS UNDERWRITING_COMMITMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='COMMITMENT' AND syn.TYPE='COMM_SHARES' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS COMM_SHARES,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='RETAIL_RETENTION' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS RETAIL_RETENTION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='DIRECTED_SHARES' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS DIRECTED_SHARES,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='RETAIL' AND syn.TYPE='TOTAL_RETAIL' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS TOTAL_RETAIL,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='GROSS_SPREAD' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS GROSS_SPREAD,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='UW_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS UW_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS MANAGEMENT_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS SELLING_CONCESSION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='RETAIL_FEE' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS RETAIL_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS MANAGEMENT_FEE_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='UW_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS UW_FEE_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS SELLING_CONCESSION_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='INCENTIVE_FEE_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS INCENTIVE_FEE_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN syn.IDENTIFIER='ECONOMICS' AND syn.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN syn.VALUE END)
           AS POT_SPLIT_PER
    FROM TABLE_SYNDICATES syn
    GROUP BY syn.revenue_id,
             syn.syndicate_code
),
attr AS (
  SELECT attr.DEAL_NUM,
         attr.EXTERNAL_ID,
         attr.syndicate_CODE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='UW_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS UW_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS MANAGEMENT_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS SELLING_CONCESSION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='RETAIL_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS RETAIL_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='REIMBURSEMENT_AMOUNT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS REIMBURSEMENT_AMOUNT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='IS_CITI_ENTITY' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           as IS_CITI_ENTITY,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='IS_BND' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           as IS_BND,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='syndicate_ROLE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           as syndicate_ROLE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='CARVEOUT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS CARVEOUT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='CARVEOUT_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS CARVEOUT_ADJUSTMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='RETAIL_SELL_CONCESSION' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS RETAIL_SELL_CONCESSION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='ADJUSTED_UW_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS ADJUSTED_UW_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='ADJUSTED_MANAGEMENT_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS ADJUSTED_MANAGEMENT_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='TOTAL_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS TOTAL_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='GROSS_FEE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS GROSS_FEE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='DESIGNATION_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS DESIGNATION_ADJUSTMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='OUT_OF_POCKET_EXPENSE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS OUT_OF_POCKET_EXPENSE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='STABILIZATION_EXPENSE' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS STABILIZATION_EXPENSE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='STABILIZATION_ADJUSTMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS STABILIZATION_ADJUSTMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='INITIAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS INITIAL_SETTLEMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='FINAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS FINAL_SETTLEMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN attr.TYPE='TOTAL_SETTLEMENT' THEN attr.VALUE END)
           AS TOTAL_SETTLEMENT
  FROM   TABLE_ATTRIBUTES attr
  WHERE  attr.IDENTIFIER='ATTRIBUTES'
  GROUP BY
         attr.DEAL_NUM,
         attr.EXTERNAL_ID,
         attr.syndicate_CODE
),
fee AS (
  SELECT fee.revenue_id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='GROSS_SPREAD_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS GROSS_SPREAD_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='YIELD' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS YIELD,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='GLOBAL_COORDINATOR' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS GLOBAL_COORDINATOR,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='GLOBAL_COORDINATOR_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS GLOBAL_COORDINATOR_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='UNDERWRITING' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS UNDERWRITING,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='UNDERWRITING_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS UNDERWRITING_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='MANAGEMENT' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS MANAGEMENT,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='MANAGEMENT_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS MANAGEMENT_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS SELL_CONCESSION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='SELLING_CONCESSION_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS SELL_CONCESSION_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='DESIGNATION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS DESIGNATION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='ADJUSTED_DESIGNATION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS ADJUSTED_DESIGNATION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='INCENTIVE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS INCENTIVE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='INCENTIVE_PER' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS INCENTIVE_PER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='SPONSOR' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS SPONSOR,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='PRAEPICIUM' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS PRAEPICIUM, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='RETAIL_UNDERWRITING' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS RETAIL_UNDERWRITING,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='DIRECTED_SHARE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS DIRECTED_SHARE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='TOTAL' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS TOTAL,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='USE_INCENTIVE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS USE_INCENTIVE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='RE_ALLOWANCE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS RE_ALLOWANCE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fee.TYPE='EXPENSE' THEN fee.VALUE END) AS EXPENSE
  FROM   TABLE_FEES fee
  WHERE  fee.IDENTIFIER='FEES'
  GROUP BY fee.revenue_id
)
select deal.DEAL_NUM,
       deal.EXTERNAL_ID,
       deal.APP_VERSION,
       syn.syndicate_code,
       syn.syndicate_NAME,
       deal.DEAL_TYPE,
       syn,UNDERWRITING_COMMITMENT,
       syn.COMM_SHARES,
       syn.RETAIL_RETENTION,
       syn.DIRECTED_SHARES,
       syn.TOTAL_RETAIL,
       syn.GROSS_SPREAD,
       COALESCE(attr.UW_FEE, syn.UW_FEE) AS UW_FEE,
       COALESCE(attr.MANAGEMENT_FEE, syn.MANAGEMENT_FEE) AS MANAGEMENT_FEE,
       COALESCE(attr.SELLING_CONCESSION, syn.SELLING_CONCESSION) AS SELLING_CONCESSION,
       COALESCE(attr.RETAIL_FEE, syn.RETAIL_FEE) AS RETAIL_FEE,
       syn.MANAGEMENT_FEE_PER,
       syn.UW_FEE_PER,
       syn.SELLING_CONCESSION_PER,
       syn.INCENTIVE_FEE_PER,
       fee.GROSS_SPREAD_PER,
       fee.YIELD,
       COALESCE(attr.GLOBAL_COORDINATOR, fee.GLOBAL_COORDINATOR) AS GLOBAL_COORDINATOR,
       fee.GLOBAL_COORDINATOR_PER,
       fee.UNDERWRITING,
       fee.UNDERWRITING_PER,
       fee.MANAGEMENT,
       fee.MANAGEMENT_PER,
       fee.SELL_CONCESSION,
       fee.SELL_CONCESSION_PER,
       COALESCE(attr.DESIGNATION, fee.DESIGNATION) AS DESIGNATION,
       fee.ADJUSTED_DESIGNATION,
       COALESCE(attr.INCENTIVE_FEE, fee.INCENTIVE) AS INCENTIVE,
       fee.INCENTIVE_PER,
       COALESCE(attr.SPONSOR, fee.SPONSOR) AS SPONSOR,
       COALESCE(attr.PRAEPICIUM, fee.PRAEPICIUM) AS PRAEPICIUM, 
       fee.RETAIL_UNDERWRITING,
       fee.DIRECTED_SHARE,
       fee.TOTAL,
       fee.USE_INCENTIVE,
       syn.POT_SPLIT_PER,
       COALESCE(attr.RE_ALLOWANCE, fee.RE_ALLOWANCE) AS RE_ALLOWANCE,
       COALESCE(attr.INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION, fee.INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION) AS INTERNAL_SELLING_CONCESSION,
       fee.EXPENSE,
       attr.REIMBURSEMENT_AMOUNT,
       attr.IS_CITI_ENTITY,
       attr.IS_BND,
       attr.syndicate_ROLE,
       attr.CARVEOUT,
       attr.CARVEOUT_ADJUSTMENT,
       attr.RETAIL_SELL_CONCESSION,
       attr.ADJUSTED_UW_FEE,
       attr.ADJUSTED_MANAGEMENT_FEE,
       attr.TOTAL_FEE,
       attr.GROSS_FEE,
       attr.DESIGNATION_ADJUSTMENT,
       attr.OUT_OF_POCKET_EXPENSE,
       attr.STABILIZATION_EXPENSE,
       attr.STABILIZATION_ADJUSTMENT,
       attr.ADJUSTMENT_COMMENT,
       attr.INITIAL_SETTLEMENT,
       attr.FINAL_SETTLEMENT,
       attr.TOTAL_SETTLEMENT
from   TABLE_DEALS deal
       LEFT JOIN syn ON deal.ID = syn.revenue_id
       LEFT JOIN fee ON deal.ID = fee.revenue_id
       LEFT JOIN attr ON deal.DEAL_NUM = attr.DEAL_NUM AND deal.EXTERNAL_ID = attr.EXTERNAL_ID AND syn.syndicate_code = attr.syndicate_CODE
where  (deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.APP_version, deal.create_ts) in (select d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID, MAX(d.APP_version), MAX(create_ts) from TABLEDEALS d group by d.DEAL_NUM, d.EXTERNAL_ID)
group by deal.DEAL_NUM, deal.EXTERNAL_ID, deal.app_version, syn.syndicate_code;


Replace the self-join of TABLE_DEALS with an analytic function:
select
    deal.deal_num, deal.external_id, deal.app_version, syn.syndicate_code,
    max(syn.syndicate_name) as syndicate_name
    -- ...
from
(
    select
        table_deals.*,
        rank() over (partition by deal_num, external_id order by app_version desc, create_ts desc) last_when_1
    from table_deals
) deal
left join table_syndicates syn
    on deal.id = syn.revenue_id
left join table_fees fee
    on deal.id = fee.revenue_id
left join table_deal_attributes attr
    on deal.deal_num = attr.deal_num
    and deal.external_id = attr.external_id
    and syn.syndicate_code = attr.syndicate_code
where deal.last_when_1 = 1
group by deal.deal_num, deal.external_id, deal.app_version, syn.syndicate_code;

If you're still having problems, gather statistics on the relevant tables, re-run the query, and replace the explain plan with a more powerful SQL Monitor Report. Run a query like select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('your sql_id') from dual; and post the text results in your question.
